# Decimal values getting modify while parse string into JObject

Tags: c#

Input json

```
{
    "ErrorMessage":"Transaction has been authorized successfully",
    "ControlId":1000.00,
    "Authorizations":[
        {
            "RMATranUUID":"1c1a88f7-d6cf-4ae8-87d3-ba06e9d9fe36",
            "Payments":[
                {
                    "PaymentNumber":"1",
                    "TotalPaymentsNumber":24,
                    "AmountDue":1000.0,
                    "AmountPaid":0.00
                }
            ],
            "Term":24,
            "OTBReleaseAmount":null
        },
        {
            "RMATranUUID":"b012ba9c-2dbd-4961-8959-ec0afbafbe13",
            "OTBReleaseAmount":null
        }
    ]
}
```

Output json, after parsing

```
        JObject jsonPacket = JObject.Parse(inputString);
```

//Line no second changes 1000.00 to 1000.0

```
{
    "ErrorMessage":"Transaction has been authorized successfully",
    "ControlId":1000.0,
    "Authorizations":[
        {
            "RMATranUUID":"1c1a88f7-d6cf-4ae8-87d3-ba06e9d9fe36",
            "Payments":[
                {
                    "PaymentNumber":"1",
                    "TotalPaymentsNumber":24,
                    "AmountDue":1000.0,
                    "AmountPaid":0.00
                }
            ],
            "Term":24,
            "OTBReleaseAmount":null
        },
        {
            "RMATranUUID":"b012ba9c-2dbd-4961-8959-ec0afbafbe13",
            "OTBReleaseAmount":null
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Mathematically, 1000.00 is exactly equal to 1000.0 - Why is that a problem? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @MilosMrdovic Thats not necessarily true (although I doubt its appliable to the question at hand). If precision is a relevant factor, `1000`, `1000.0` and `1000.00` can mean very different things.

Comment: @InBetween Well, that's why I wrote "Mathematically". In other words, I'm asking whether the precision is a relevant factor applicable to this question. If he shared some more info so that we understand the context of the problem, we might be able to offer a workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The reason is JObject at parsing doubles executes like this under the hood:

```
double data;
double.TryParse("1214.00", NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, out data);
```

As data is of type double and double is floating point number, you didn't get the value you expect.

Either, you create a POCO and parse it into it, or you can do this:

```
string json = "{    \"ErrorMessage\":\"Transaction has been authorized successfully\",    \"ControlId\":1000.00,    \"Authorizations\":[        {            \"RMATranUUID\":\"1c1a88f7-d6cf-4ae8-87d3-ba06e9d9fe36\",            \"Payments\":[                {                    \"PaymentNumber\":\"1\",                    \"TotalPaymentsNumber\":24,                    \"AmountDue\":1000.0,                    \"AmountPaid\":0.00                }            ],            \"Term\":24,            \"OTBReleaseAmount\":null        },        {            \"RMATranUUID\":\"b012ba9c-2dbd-4961-8959-ec0afbafbe13\",            \"OTBReleaseAmount\":null        }    ]}";

var jsonReader = new JsonTextReader(new StringReader(json));
jsonReader.FloatParseHandling = FloatParseHandling.Decimal;

var jObject = JObject.Load(jsonReader);

Console.WriteLine(jObject["ControlId"].Value<decimal>()); // 1000.00
Console.WriteLine(jObject); // prints your actual json
```